# Finding Map distance and Time with Latitude and Longitude?

Tags: r, latitude-longitude, ggmap

I have a requirement to find driving distance and time .
i found a way to do it.
when i manually type Latitude and Longitude it is working fine.
Code

[image: working]

But my data is in CSV file and it has multiple locations.
it is not working.
code
[image: Not Working]

```
Error
```

Error: 1: Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !
Bytes: 0xE8 0x72 0x65 0x73

Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks 
Pavan

Comment: Please do not share code as screenshot, but as text (so that we can copy-paste it)

Comment: And share your data using `dput(head(a))`, so that others can use it directly

Comment: Thanks for speed reply, here is the sample data                        LATITUDELONGITUDE dlan dlat
17.3897 78.478 17.4372 78.4441
17.3742 78.5121 17.4372 78.4441
17.4878 78.4127 17.4372 78.4441
17.3849 78.4468 17.4372 78.4441

Comment: You are trying to find the distance from a place called 'LATITUDE LONGITUDE' to a place called 'dlat dlon'. I think you mean `origin <- paste(a$LATITUDE, a$LONGITUDE, sep = "+")`

Comment: Eumenedies  Thanks Man , It is Working